# 'ConsoleApplication1.CS.adds(double, double)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

What is the problem with my code here? When I try to run the application in debug mode I get an error saying "**'ConsoleApplication1.CS.adds(double, double)' is inaccessible due to its protection level**" and the same with **subs** and **muls** methods in each class.

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cs cal = new cs();
            double a, b;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter First Num: ");
            a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Num: ");
            b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Summation = {0}\nDifference = {1}\nMultiplication = {2}", cal.adds(a, b), cal.subs(a, b), cal.muls(a, b));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class cs : cd { static double adds(double x, double y) {return x + y;} }
    class cd : cm { double subs(double x, double y) {return x - y;} }
    class cm { static double muls(double x, double y) {return x * y;} }
}
```

Comment: Those are `private` methods and so can't be called from outside the class.  Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the code.

First: **you are omitting the access modifiers** from your method definitions. By default C# marks them as `private`, which means your methods can be only used in the same class (not even in descendants). The `Program` is a different class from `cs`, therefore access is not allowed.

Second: **you are accessing the static methods by a class instance**. To invoke a static method, you should use the class's name before it, instead of an object of that class.

So, the compilable version would be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cs cal = new cs();
        double a, b;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Num: ");
        a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Num: ");
        b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Summation = {0}\nDifference = {1}\nMultiplication = {2}", cs.adds(a, b), cal.subs(a, b), cs.muls(a, b));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class cs : cd { public static double adds(double x, double y) { return x + y; } }
class cd : cm { public double subs(double x, double y) { return x - y; } }
class cm { public static double muls(double x, double y) { return x * y; } }
```

Comment: @ELMOIV well the error message is pretty much self-explainatory: instead of `variable.Method()` use `Type.Method()`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I changed the code without copying yours after edit so I missed the class name (cs) before the static methods.
Thanks very much :)